# Why shouldn't we swear or curse- LDS

Tags: lds, cursing

So here are the reasons I've come up with why we are commanded not to curse or swear.

1. Some curse words have vulgar and awful meanings.
2. Culturally it is seen as unprofessional, unintelligent and impolite.

On the issue that some curse words have vulgar and awful meanings. I fully understand why these shouldn't be used. But most swear words do not have awful meanings.

As for it being a cultural issue, I agree, you do seem less professional and intelligent. But that all depends on who you are around and how serious of a word it is. For example, using the word Heck as an adult rather than Hell in some settings can be seen a childish, unprofessional and unintelligent. Also, most adults don't find it impolite to swear when something serious has just happened.

Also, why is it not ok to say a swear word, but is ok to say a replacement word that means the same exact thing and is used in the same exact situations. Just like the word crap and the the "s" word.

I've been researching what swear words actually are and why society even created them and I found that the reason society has swear words is a way to convey lots of emotion. For example, the seldom times I hear my dad swear, I know he means business and what he is swearing about is serious. Also, when I was younger and in school, whenever the class was rowdy and the teacher couldn't get our attention, they would swear and the whole class would immediately be quiet.

I understand that overuse of a swear word is wrong because then it defeats the purpose of being used to convey emotions. But when the alternative to swearing is raising your voice, I see swearing as useful.

I'm not referring to taking the Lords name in vain or to words that have dirty meanings. I'm talking about why is it bad to occasionally use a swear word that has a perfectly appropriate definition, and to use it at times when trying to convey emotion with a group of people where they don't perceive what you said as impolite.

Society created the idea of certain words being curse words. Nothing is inherently wrong with the words themselves. So when your either by yourself or your around a group of people where it is socially acceptable to use a certain curse word in a certain situation, why should you still not use it?

Comment: This is a good question but doesn't quite fit this site. We don't do "Why is X a sin?" type questions as there are too many possible answers.

Comment: @LCIII: The question is asking Why it's a sin from an LDS perspective. I think on topic. There should be a clear cut answer for why the LDS church says so.

Comment: More interesting might be the threshold of what is considered a swear word. I heard people say "crap" and "sucks" at the podium in an LDS testimonial meeting. It struck me as odd, but not offensive. It made me wonder just how far is tolerable and under what circumstances.

Comment: Part of the problem with this question is that it's confusing terms.  Swearing, cursing, and vulgarities are (traditionally) three distinct concepts, but are commonly all referred to as 'swearing' in modern language. Swearing, traditionally, is making an oath, and is typically considered sinful only when the oath is made lightly (ex. Matthew 5:36). Cursing is a wishful statement of ill will to someone ("May a thousand bees fly up your nose!") and vulgarity is a very local, social concept, and simply involves using "rude words," and is often not considered "sinful," but simply "rude."

Comment: (cont'd) There are clearly verses (such as Matthew 5:36) which say swearing, in the traditional sense, is wrong. But due to the language overlap between these three concepts, I believe it's often said, or at least assumed, that all three are morally wrong. A good answer ought to address all three concepts separately.

Answer (score 2):

The teachings in James 3 on the relations between language and character are certainly in accord with the rest of LDS teaching and could profitably be more repeated and expounded more than they are.

However, in addition, Nephi mentions speaking with the tongue of angels (2 Ne 31:14 and 32:2) as one of the gifts of the Spirit, one that is not mentioned in the other lists. The injunction "I am God; give heed to my word, which is quick and powerful, sharper than a two-edged sword, to the dividing asunder of both joints and marrow" is repeated several times in the early revelations in the Doctrine and Covenants (as well as Hebrews 4:12)

These teachings suggest that the popular notion that crude, vulgar, obscene, or profane speech is especially strong or expressive is entirely wrong.